# Errors thrown when trying to use the mdframed package

Tags: errors, installing, mdframed

I am running Ubuntu, so unfortunately I don't get the nice Console way of installing new LaTeX packages, I have to install them manually.

From CTAN, I found the [`mdframed`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/mdframed/) package, downloaded and extracted the zip, and placed the files so that I now have:

```
usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/mdframed/
```

With a load of files in:

```
md-frame-#.mdf (where # is 0 through 3)
md-framepre-#.mdf (where # is 0 through 3)
mdframed.sty
mdframedpre.sty
mdframed-doc-en.pdf and *.tex
README
```

At which point I ran `mktexlsr`, which outputted a few lines, and seemed happy.

Now when I try to `\usepackage{mdframed}`, and compile it (I know compile isn't the right word, I just can't remember the correct term atm), my console fills with errors, with the variety of "Undefined Control Sequence"/ "Missing Number, treated as zero"/ "Illegal unit of measurement"/ "Illegal Parameter", and probably a few that I've missed.

Here are the first 4 errors:

```
2011-09-23 12:27:59,596 DEBUG ToolView - Issue{' Undefined control sequence \newrobustcmd.', 91, None, file:///home/peter/Latex//usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/mdframed/mdframed.sty, 2}
2011-09-23 12:27:59,597 DEBUG ToolView - Issue{' Missing \begin{document}.', 91, None, file:///home/peter/Latex//usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/mdframed/mdframed.sty, 2}
2011-09-23 12:27:59,598 DEBUG ToolView - Issue{' Undefined control sequence \mdf@option@length.', 91, None, file:///home/peter/Latex//usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/mdframed/mdframed.sty, 2}
2011-09-23 12:27:59,598 DEBUG ToolView - Issue{' Missing number, treated as zero.', 93, None, file:///home/peter/Latex//usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/mdframed/mdframed.sty, 2}
```

After searching for `\newrobustcmd`, I couldn't find any documentation on LaTeX for it.

Also, after opening `mdframed.sty`, I found that the lines were 1 off (eg, The debugger gave `\newrobustcmd` to be on line 91 whereas gedit says its on line 92).

The `mdframed.sty` I am using can be found here (same link as above): http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/mdframed/mdframed.sty.

Comment: You need additional packages like `etoolbox`. All required packages are listed in the documentation.

Comment: You should install TeXLive 2011. Then you have the update-manager tlmgr to get all new packages.

Comment: @Marco If `mdframed` has package dependencies, shouldn't it flag them as errors and not just warnings so that this behaviour doesn't arise?

Comment: @Peter: A tip from a Debian user: Never ever install an additional LaTeX package into `/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex` or `/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex`. Use `/usr/local/share/texmf/tex/latex` for this purpose.

Comment: @mhp Is this for security reasons or for compile settings?

Comment: The current Ubuntu TeXLive is from 2009 so its packages are a couple of years behind the CTAN versions; this can give rise to incompatibilities. Having a full Ubuntu texlive install should resolve many dependencies (e.g. `etoolbox` is in Synaptic's texlive-latex-extra) but, as suggested by others, installing TeX Live 2011 is likely to be better if you want to use a wider range of packages, or more current ones, than Ubuntu's texlive provides. You can have both the Ubuntu version and the TeX Live versions installed (I do) and use path settings to use the one you want to.

Comment: @Peter: This is particularly for eliminating the risk of confusing the package manager when upgrading the system. Note that `/usr/local/share/texmf` is searched before `/usr/share/texmf` and `/usr/share/texmf-texlive`. So you can put up-to-date versions of any LaTeX packages there.

Comment: @Marco Can you post what you said as an answer so I could mark this question as answered?

Comment: @AlanMunn: I will change it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`mdframed` requires additional packages like `etoolbox`. To prevent such errors you should install [TeXLive 2011](http://www.tug.org/texlive/). Then you can use the update manager [tlmgr](http://www.tug.org/texlive/tlmgr.html) to install and update all your packages.

Comment: Sorry - it just occurred to me that you were one of the people who created mdframed. I just wanted to say I appreciate the work you've done - now that I've got it working its a really useful package.

Comment: @Marco Daniel, I installed TeX Live 2013, but I still get ! LaTeX Error: File `mdframed.sty' not found. when I compile. What could be the problem?