# Errors after TeX Live 2012 update on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: tex-core, ubuntu

I wanted to use `mdframed` package but I was getting the error package not found. I followed the [advice](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29274/errors-thrown-when-trying-to-use-the-mdframed-package) here to update to Text Live 2011. However, I figured out there is Tex Live 2012 and therefore installed it using [the instructions here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/163682/how-do-i-install-the-latest-tex-live-2012).

Now, several packages I was using are throwing up error...

`stmaryrd.sty`,`comma.sty`,`appendix.sty` not found! Now, how do I get get rid of these errors and start using `mdframed`? Any help appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to TeX-SX! You may have a look at [our starter page](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) for a quick intro if you wish to familiarize yourself with our format. I suggest you to have a look to [How to install “vanilla” TeXLive on Debian or Ubuntu?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1092/how-to-install-vanilla-texlive-on-debian-or-ubuntu): it should solve the problem.